# Question regarding minima and maxima related to its relation with values?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, differential-geometry

Let us say that you took a graph of $y = x^2$.

Values of y for this parabolic graph is 1,4,9 for values of x =1,2,3.

Values for for its slope by differentiation is 2,4,6 for x = 1,2,3.$\frac{dy}{dx}$

I took its differentiated values as velocity and not differentiated (I.e y=x^2) as speed.

Q1 It travels 1m in 1sec and then 4m in 2sec.
Whereas velocity is 2m in 1sec and 4m in 2sec.
How is that possible?
Since it would also mean that it traveled 2m in 1sec which is not right.

Q2 $x^3-3x=y$
When differentiated, slope is $3x^2-3$.
Values of x from this quadratic = 1 and -1.

When I put these values in the 1st equation ,
I get +2 and -2.

My sir said these are values of minima and maxima function.

What is the difference of these values with if I had directly put values in the differentiated equation.
For which I get =0 for both.Why are these not values of function of maxima and minima?

Q3 why are differentiated values equal to 0.
Y= X^2 , its $\frac{dy}{dx}$ =2x =0, Why not equal to tan theta which is the slope.

Comment: This post, I think, is quite difficult to read. I see at least three different things talked about. First, it's about some graph of a quadratic function and its slope, then about some speeds, and then about a graph of a cubic function. Please focus on one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to Question 1:**

If you know, the acceleration will be
$$a=\dfrac{\textrm dv}{\textrm dt}= 2$$
So, the system will be accelerated. The formula $\text{speed = distance/time}$ is not valid when $a\neq 0$. The correct formula is
$$\text{average speed} = \frac{\text{total distance}}{\text{total time}}$$
And this holds correctly for your example.

Speed at $0$th second is $0$ and speed at $1$st second is $2$. So, average speed is $\frac{0+2}{2}=1$ as expected.
$$\left[\text{Average}=\frac{\text{Sum of all values}}{\text{Number of values}}\right]$$

**Answer to Question 2 and 3:**

You misunderstood things. *Maxima and minima are the maximum and minimum values that a function can have, not the differentiated function in a given interval.* So, $y=x^3-3x$ can be at least $-2$ or at most $2$ in the interval $[0,1]$, *not* $y=3x^2-3$.

This is the *rule* to set the differentiated function to $0$. $\dfrac{\textrm dv}{\textrm dt}$ is already the slope, so *why would we equate it to slope*?

Note that at the maximum and minimum values, the slope is zero. To find the maxima and minima, we thus equate it to zero. Just remember it for now, *it is a rule*.

Hope this is clear. Ask anything if required :)

Comment: For q1 I meant the undifferentiated one is distance travelled by it.

Comment: Just like you wrote for Q3 , that dy/dx is already the slope. So it has equate to tan theta right.If I say Distance / time is velocity.Then it will equate to velocity right not zero.

Comment: Which will in turn may or may equal to zero.Since both are tending to zero.If I say delta x is 0.0001 and delta y is 0.001.It has value greater than 0 for sure.

Comment: Is it possible to think my Q 2 in terms of velocity and distance travelled.

Comment: Please help in this.

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly. Read it again and tell now any doubts!

Comment: I know that @DavidK, however I didn't say that in my answer because I felt it would create more confusion to the OP. He was already confused about extrema; by telling him about local and global extrema would rather increase his confusion.

Comment: Anyways, I edited my answer to abide by your point.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 That seems a reasonable way to handle that concern. There were too many points of confusion exhibited in the question and comments to allow answering everything in the most complete way all at once. I agree with your point about increasing confusion.